# No sound Ubuntu impish 21.10 Kernel 5.13.0 Samsung Galaxy Book Flex2

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, 21.10

community,

i get a Galaxy Book Flex2 (NP930QCA-KA3DE) from work. Windows goes completely to trash :), formated the whole disk and installed Ubuntu imprish.

After get wifi working with @heynnema i hope we get sound working.

I see on config/audio on gnome micro working on the aplitude moving. But there is no sound on anything, also no sound on klicking on sound test.

Here is my logs:

#### sudo dmidecode -t0 -t1

```
# dmidecode 3.3
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.3.0 present.

Handle 0x0000, DMI type 0, 26 bytes
BIOS Information
    Vendor: American Megatrends International, LLC.
    Version: P09AJN.047.210930.MK
    Release Date: 09/30/2021
    Address: 0xF0000
    Runtime Size: 64 kB
    ROM Size: 0 MB
    Characteristics:
        PCI is supported
        BIOS is upgradeable
        BIOS shadowing is allowed
        Boot from CD is supported
        Selectable boot is supported
        BIOS ROM is socketed
        EDD is supported
        ACPI is supported
        BIOS boot specification is supported
        Targeted content distribution is supported
        UEFI is supported
    BIOS Revision: 5.19

Handle 0x0001, DMI type 1, 27 bytes
System Information
    Manufacturer: SAMSUNG ELECTRONICS CO., LTD.
    Product Name: 930QCA
    Version: P09AJN
    Wake-up Type: Power Switch
    Family: Galaxy Book Series
```

#### inxi -Fxxxrz

```
System:    Kernel: 5.13.0-20-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 11.2.0 Desktop: GNOME 40.5 tk: GTK 3.24.30 
           wm: gnome-shell dm: GDM3 41.rc Distro: Ubuntu 21.10 (Impish Indri) 
Machine:   Type: Convertible System: SAMSUNG product: 930QCA v: P09AJN serial: <filter> Chassis: type: 31 serial: <filter> 
           Mobo: SAMSUNG model: NP930QCA-KA3DE v: SGLA830A0H-C01-G001-S0001+10.0.19042 serial: <filter> 
           UEFI: American Megatrends LLC. v: P09AJN.047.210930.MK date: 09/30/2021 
Battery:   ID-1: BAT1 charge: 59.6 Wh (87.9%) condition: 67.8/67.0 Wh (101.1%) volts: 16.5 min: 15.4 
           model: SAMSUNG Electronics SR Real Battery type: Li-ion serial: <filter> status: Discharging cycles: 4 
CPU:       Info: Quad Core model: 11th Gen Intel Core i5-1135G7 bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Tiger Lake rev: 1 cache: L2: 8 MiB 
           flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 38707 
           Speed: 953 MHz min/max: 400/4200 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 953 2: 929 3: 931 4: 995 5: 940 6: 1546 7: 797 8: 531 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] vendor: Samsung Co driver: i915 v: kernel bus-ID: 00:02.0 
           chip-ID: 8086:9a49 class-ID: 0300 
           Device-2: Generic 720p HD Camera type: USB driver: uvcvideo bus-ID: 3-6:8 chip-ID: 2b7e:0134 class-ID: 0e02 
           serial: <filter> 
           Display: wayland server: X.Org 1.21.1.2 compositor: gnome-shell driver: loaded: i915 
           note: n/a (using device driver) resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz s-dpi: 96 
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel Xe Graphics (TGL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 21.2.2 direct render: Yes 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel vendor: Samsung Co driver: N/A bus-ID: 00:05.0 chip-ID: 8086:9a19 class-ID: 0480 
           Device-2: Intel Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Audio vendor: Samsung Co driver: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl bus-ID: 00:1f.3 
           chip-ID: 8086:a0c8 class-ID: 0401 
           Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.13.0-20-generic running: yes 
           Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.0 running: yes 
           Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.32 running: yes 
Network:   Device-1: Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX201 driver: iwlwifi v: iwlwifi-stack-public:master:9340:55438a77 port: 3000 
           bus-ID: 00:14.3 chip-ID: 8086:a0f0 class-ID: 0280 
           IF: wlo1 state: up mac: <filter> 
           IF-ID-1: wwan0 state: down mac: <filter> 
Bluetooth: Device-1: Intel type: USB driver: btusb v: 0.8 bus-ID: 3-10:10 chip-ID: 8087:0026 class-ID: e001 
           Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 1 state: down bt-service: enabled,running rfk-block: hardware: no software: yes 
           address: <filter> 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 1.14 TiB used: 73.17 GiB (6.3%) 
           ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Samsung model: MZ9LQ256HAJD-000 size: 238.47 GiB speed: 31.6 Gb/s lanes: 4 type: SSD 
           serial: <filter> rev: FXV70K0Q temp: 32.9 C scheme: GPT 
           ID-2: /dev/sda type: USB vendor: Samsung model: PSSD T7 Touch size: 931.51 GiB type: SSD serial: <filter> 
           scheme: MBR 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 233.18 GiB used: 73.16 GiB (31.4%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2 
           ID-2: /boot/efi size: 511 MiB used: 5.2 MiB (1.0%) fs: vfat dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1 
Swap:      ID-1: swap-1 type: file size: 2 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) priority: -2 file: /swapfile 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 47.0 C mobo: 47.0 C 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Repos:     Packages: 2124 apt: 2113 snap: 11 
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list 
           1: deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ impish main restricted
           2: deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ impish-updates main restricted
           3: deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ impish universe
           4: deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ impish-updates universe
           5: deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ impish multiverse
           6: deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ impish-updates multiverse
           7: deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ impish-backports main restricted universe multiverse
           8: deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu impish partner
           9: deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security main restricted
           10: deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security universe
           11: deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security multiverse
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_typora_io_linux-impish.list 
           1: deb https://typora.io/linux ./
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release.list 
           1: deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/brave-browser-archive-keyring.gpg arch=amd64] https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/ stable main
           No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/fingerprint-ubuntu-fingerprint-gui-impish.list 
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-audio-dev-ubuntu-alsa-daily-impish.list 
           1: deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/alsa-daily/ubuntu/ impish main
           No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yann1ck-ubuntu-onedrive-impish.list 
Info:      Processes: 299 Uptime: 13h 6m wakeups: 3733 Memory: 15.31 GiB used: 2.49 GiB (16.3%) Init: systemd v: 248 
           runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 11.2.0 alt: 11 Shell: Bash v: 5.1.8 running-in: gnome-terminal inxi: 3.3.06
```

#### lspci -vvvtkPPnnqq

```
-[0000:00]-+-00.0  Intel Corporation 11th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers [8086:9a14]
           +-02.0  Intel Corporation TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] [8086:9a49]
           +-04.0  Intel Corporation TigerLake-LP Dynamic Tuning Processor Participant [8086:9a03]
           +-05.0  Intel Corporation Device [8086:9a19]
           +-07.0-[01-2b]--
           +-07.1-[2c-56]--
           +-08.0  Intel Corporation GNA Scoring Accelerator module [8086:9a11]
           +-0d.0  Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt 4 USB Controller [8086:9a13]
           +-0d.2  Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt 4 NHI #0 [8086:9a1b]
           +-12.0  Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Integrated Sensor Hub [8086:a0fc]
           +-14.0  Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP USB 3.2 Gen 2x1 xHCI Host Controller [8086:a0ed]
           +-14.2  Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Shared SRAM [8086:a0ef]
           +-14.3  Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201 [8086:a0f0]
           +-15.0  Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 [8086:a0e8]
           +-15.1  Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 [8086:a0e9]
           +-15.2  Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #2 [8086:a0ea]
           +-15.3  Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #3 [8086:a0eb]
           +-16.0  Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Management Engine Interface [8086:a0e0]
           +-1d.0-[57]----00.0  Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller 980 [144d:a809]
           +-1f.0  Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP LPC Controller [8086:a082]
           +-1f.3  Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller [8086:a0c8]
           +-1f.4  Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP SMBus Controller [8086:a0a3]
           \-1f.5  Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP SPI Controller [8086:a0a4]
```

#### lspci -nnk | grep -i audio -A2

```
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller [0401]: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller [8086:a0c8] (rev 20)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Sound
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller [144d:c194]
    Kernel driver in use: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl
00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP SMBus Controller [8086:a0a3] (rev 20)
```

#### cat /proc/asound/cards

```
 0 [sofhdadsp      ]: sof-hda-dsp - sof-hda-dsp
                      SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.-930QCA-P09AJN-NP930QCA_KA3DE
```

#### uname -rm

```
5.13.0-20-generic x86_64
```

#### lsmod | grep snd

```
snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp    24576  7
snd_soc_intel_hda_dsp_common    20480  1 snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp
snd_soc_hdac_hdmi      36864  1 snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     61440  1
snd_hda_codec_realtek   147456  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    81920  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_soc_dmic           16384  1
snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl    16384  4
snd_sof_intel_hda_common    98304  1 snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl
soundwire_intel        40960  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_sof_intel_hda      20480  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_sof_pci            20480  2 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl
snd_sof_xtensa_dsp     16384  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_sof               135168  2 snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_soc_hdac_hda       24576  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_hda_ext_core       32768  4 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hdmi,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_soc_acpi_intel_match    49152  2 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl
snd_soc_acpi           16384  2 snd_soc_acpi_intel_match,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
ledtrig_audio          16384  2 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_sof
snd_soc_core          290816  7 soundwire_intel,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hdmi,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_dmic,snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp
snd_compress           28672  1 snd_soc_core
ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_hda_intel          53248  0
snd_intel_dspcfg       28672  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_intel_sdw_acpi     20480  2 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_intel_dspcfg
snd_hda_codec         147456  7 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_intel_hda_dsp_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp
snd_hda_core           94208  11 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_intel_hda_dsp_common,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hdmi,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               118784  13 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,soundwire_intel,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hdmi,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
snd_seq_midi           20480  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            36864  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                73728  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
snd_timer              40960  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
snd                    94208  27 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_soc_hdac_hdmi,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp,snd_rawmidi
soundcore              16384  1 snd
```

#### lsmod | grep audio

```
ledtrig_audio          16384  2 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_sof
```

#### lsmod | grep sound

```
soundwire_intel        40960  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
soundwire_generic_allocation    16384  1 soundwire_intel
soundwire_cadence      32768  1 soundwire_intel
soundwire_bus          81920  3 soundwire_intel,soundwire_generic_allocation,soundwire_cadence
snd_soc_core          290816  7 soundwire_intel,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hdmi,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_dmic,snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp
snd_pcm               118784  13 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,soundwire_intel,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hdmi,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
soundcore              16384  1 snd
```

#### aplay -l

```
**** Liste der Hardware-Geräte (PLAYBACK) ****
Karte 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], Gerät 0: HDA Analog (*) []
  Sub-Geräte: 0/1
  Sub-Gerät #0: subdevice #0
Karte 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], Gerät 1: HDA Digital (*) []
  Sub-Geräte: 1/1
  Sub-Gerät #0: subdevice #0
Karte 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], Gerät 3: HDMI1 (*) []
  Sub-Geräte: 1/1
  Sub-Gerät #0: subdevice #0
Karte 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], Gerät 4: HDMI2 (*) []
  Sub-Geräte: 1/1
  Sub-Gerät #0: subdevice #0
Karte 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], Gerät 5: HDMI3 (*) []
  Sub-Geräte: 1/1
  Sub-Gerät #0: subdevice #0
```

#### pactl list short sinks

```
0   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic.HiFi__hw_sofhdadsp_5__sink    module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
1   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic.HiFi__hw_sofhdadsp_4__sink    module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
2   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic.HiFi__hw_sofhdadsp_3__sink    module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
3   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic.HiFi__hw_sofhdadsp__sink  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 48000Hz   IDLE
```

#### inxi -A

```
Audio:     Device-1: Intel driver: N/A 
           Device-2: Intel Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Audio driver: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 
           Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.13.0-20-generic running: yes 
           Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.0 running: yes 
           Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.32 running: yes
```

#### dpkg -l firmware-sof-signed

#### grep -i firmware /var/log/syslog* | grep 'Oct 27'

```
Oct 27 07:42:17 flex2 kernel: [    0.230579] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
Oct 27 07:42:17 flex2 sbkeysync[664]: firmware keys:
Oct 27 07:42:17 flex2 kernel: [   13.642207] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-67.ucode failed with error -2
Oct 27 07:42:17 flex2 kernel: [   13.642226] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-66.ucode failed with error -2
Oct 27 07:42:17 flex2 kernel: [   13.642241] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-65.ucode failed with error -2
Oct 27 07:42:17 flex2 kernel: [   13.642256] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-64.ucode failed with error -2
Oct 27 07:42:17 flex2 kernel: [   13.648698] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 63.c04f3485.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-63.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
Oct 27 07:42:17 flex2 kernel: [   13.662362] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
Oct 27 07:42:17 flex2 kernel: [   13.664614] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-19-0-4.sfi
Oct 27 07:42:17 flex2 kernel: [   13.682781] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/tgl_dmc_ver2_08.bin (v2.8)
Oct 27 07:42:17 flex2 NetworkManager[602]: <info>  [1635313337.3728] manager[0x55ef459a2040]: monitoring kernel firmware directory '/lib/firmware'.
Oct 27 07:42:18 flex2 kernel: [   15.139662] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware info: version 1:6:0-18fab
Oct 27 07:42:18 flex2 kernel: [   15.139666] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware: ABI 3:17:0 Kernel ABI 3:18:0
Oct 27 07:42:18 flex2 kernel: [   15.327568] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
Oct 27 07:42:18 flex2 kernel: [   15.328331] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1624720 usecs
Oct 27 07:42:18 flex2 kernel: [   15.348370] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware revision 0.4 build 164 week 35 2021
Oct 27 07:42:23 flex2 systemd[1]: Startup finished in 6.134s (firmware) + 4.434s (loader) + 13.167s (kernel) + 7.294s (userspace) = 31.031s.
Oct 27 07:42:33 flex2 systemd[1]: Starting Firmware update daemon...
Oct 27 07:42:35 flex2 systemd[1]: Started Firmware update daemon.
```

#### error sudo apt-get install firmware-sof-signed

```
Paketlisten werden gelesen… Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut… Fertig
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen… Fertig
Die folgenden NEUEN Pakete werden installiert:
  firmware-sof-signed
0 aktualisiert, 1 neu installiert, 0 zu entfernen und 0 nicht aktualisiert.
Es müssen 550 kB an Archiven heruntergeladen werden.
Nach dieser Operation werden 10,1 MB Plattenplatz zusätzlich benutzt.
Holen:1 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/multiverse amd64 firmware-sof-signed all 1.7-1 [550 kB]
Es wurden 550 kB in 0 s geholt (2.396 kB/s).
(Lese Datenbank ... 206776 Dateien und Verzeichnisse sind derzeit installiert.)
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../firmware-sof-signed_1.7-1_all.deb ...
Entpacken von firmware-sof-signed (1.7-1) ...
dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Archivs /var/cache/apt/archives/firmware-sof-signed_1.7-1_all.deb (--unpack):
 Versuch, »/lib/firmware/intel/sof/sof-bdw.ri« zu überschreiben, welches auch in Paket linux-firmware 1.201 ist
dpkg-deb: Fehler: »einfügen«-Unterprozess wurde durch Signal (Datenübergabe unterbrochen (broken pipe)) getötet
Fehler traten auf beim Bearbeiten von:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/firmware-sof-signed_1.7-1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `dpkg -l firmware-sof-signed`.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `grep -i firmware /var/log/syslog*`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema Hello again :), I updated my post as your advice

Comment: You truncated the syslog output, so I may not have seen what I was looking for. Go ahead and (re)install `linux-firmware` and `firmware-sof-signed`. Reboot. Retest.

Comment: @heynnema what was you looking for? the syslog was full of wifi errors before. If you want i can post. `reinstalling linux-firmware` was ok but reinstalling `firmware-sof-signed get` error. I put the error in the post above.

Comment: The `firmware-sof-signed` is no big deal... it's included in `linux-firmware`. I guess I'm out of ideas for now. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

> No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yann1ck-ubuntu-onedrive-impish.list

**Disclosure:** I am the developer of the OneDrive Client for Linux - https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive

Please stop using this PPA Repo. It contains obsolete OneDrive Client Software. Please install the client correctly by following these instructions: https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/blob/master/docs/ubuntu-package-install.md